# Should this five year old question be closed?

Tags: discussion

[Vertical Tabs with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773074/vertical-tabs-with-jquery)

Essentially this question is looking for a recommendation, a topic that's now off-topic for SO. However, it's also reached the age where the topic is now irrelevant as jQuery UI has since added this functionality, and even includes a demo on their site (http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical).

Note also the the majority of answers are simply recommending plugins.

<sub>**(I am not suggesting that the question be closed due to its age)**</sub>

Comment: Just because a question is old or has a lot of views/votes does not make it subject to different close-vote logic. The only difference is because it has more than 100 views, close votes will decay after 4 days.

Comment: No, the post is not specifically asking for any external framework or library. All it states is that they are using jQuery. No recommendations are requested.

Comment: I don't see a reason why this should be closed. It's poorly written etc but still on-topic

Comment: @gunr2171 - I never said it should be close *because* it's old, I said it should be closed because a) it's asking for a recommendation which is off-topic and b) it's moot now since jQuery UI already has an example of what the person was asking for.

Comment: I don't think the fact that a question is no longer relevant because of a new version should be an argument for closure. It's often useful to know past solutions, especially when dealing with legacy software where you can't always upgrade everything you'd like. (Specifying the versions in the question and answers.)

Answer (score 6):

No, it can stay open just perfectly fine.

- The post is not specifically asking for any external framework or library. All it states is that they are using jQuery. No recommendations are requested.
- Being outdated doesn't make a post off-topic. The current top-voted answer *shows off the vertical tabs from jQuery UI*.

Comment: Then what is it asking for?

Comment: @j08691: someone to show how to do it. It's a gimme-the-codez question.

Comment: Which would be a reason to close, no?

Comment: Nah, not for an old post like this. It makes a good dupe target if nothing else.

Comment: I'm not even sure it's a "gimme-the-codez" question as such. I'd consider "gimme-the-codez" questions questions where the OP describe the complex problem they have to solve, without trying to break it down, and expecting us to provide the solution. Here the problem is broken down reasonably well.